# String Literals and Plotting with Matplotlib

Tags: python, string, matplotlib, plot

I'd like to plot an amplitude spectral density for a device with matplotlib. Typical units for these kinds of plots are sensor_units/Hz^(1/2). Because I have a few different kinds of  sensors, I'd like to pass the correct sensor_units as each time I plot, so I've written the axis label as

```
r'Coupling {}$/\sqrt{\mathrm{Hz}}$'.format(units)
```

this gives the error

```
ValueError: unexpected '{' in field name
```

What do I need to change to get this working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Double each `{` and `}` that should be interpreted literally.

```py
r'Coupling {}$/\sqrt{{\mathrm{{Hz}}}}$'.format(units)
```